# Web Service URL change is not recognized

Tags: web-services, configuration, web-config

I deployed in a production environment a .net solution that consumes a web service added as "Service reference" in visual studio.

Today the endpoint URL has changed, and I modified that URL in web.config. But when I run the solution I get the error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://93.62.150.200/LogEvent.
```

Now that sound strange to me. As you can see, the IP is 93.62....  but the new value is different.

The web.config entry (with the new value or the URL) is:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://213.92.50.215/sawfc/WS_SAWFC_Int.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsSAWFCInterfaceSoap"
            contract="it.datasphere.ws.wsSAWFCInterfaceSoap" name="wsSAWFCInterfaceSoap" />
</client>
```

I cannot reach the new web service from dev environment, so I cannot modify the Service reference there.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records: I discovered that the namespace of the web service that I was calling changed. The namespace used reflected the IP of the service, and when "on the other side" the IP changed, the developers changed also the namespace.

In this situation my service reference crashed, expecting the "old" namespace.